# C# LINQ - iterate multiple collections within IList initializer

Tags: c#, linq

I have data in an `IDictionary<string, IList<AppObject>>` collection, so it looks like this *(this is dummy text to illustrate the shape)*

```
{
    "collections": {
        "default": [
        {
            "Id": "id/1",
            "Name": "Object 1",
            "Value": 1.05
        },
        {
            "Id": "id/2",
            "Name": "Object 2",
            "Value": 2.05
        },
        {
            "Id": "id/3",
            "Name": "Object 3",
            "Value": 3.05
        },
       "default2": [
        {
            "Id": "id/4",
            "Name": "Object 4",
            "Value": 1.05
        },
        {
            "Id": "id/5",
            "Name": "Object 5",
            "Value": 2.05
        },
        {
            "Id": "id/6",
            "Name": "Object 6",
            "Value": 3.05
        },
        "default3": [
        {
            "Id": "id/7",
            "Name": "Object 7",
            "Value": 1.05
        },
        {
            "Id": "id/8",
            "Name": "Object 8",
            "Value": 2.05
        },
        {
            "Id": "id/9",
            "Name": "Object 9",
            "Value": 3.05
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine, it's simple enough. Now I am at a place where I need to pull data from it; Because of certain reasons, I need to do this inside an initializer, instead of a method, so I can't use any kind of variables. *(this is inside a `RavenDB` Transformer)*

I know how to get all of the items out of a specific collection, like so..

```
results.collections["default"].Sum( ... )
results.collections["default2"].Sum( ... )
```

But is there a `LINQ` friendly way to do this, and pick the ones I'm pulling from at the same time?

Basically, in this example, I want to sum the **Value** field of everything and get the result, without hard-coding the path to "**default**" and "**default2**", but **NOT** **default3** in one line, as a clean LINQ function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use SelectMany to do it like below:

```
results.collections.SelectMany(p => p.Value).Sum(p => p.ValueToSum);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this works in Linq2Obj:

```
var collection = new Dictionary<string, IList<AppObject>>();
    collection.Add("Default", new List<AppObject>() { new AppObject() {Value=1}});
    collection.Add("Default2", new List<AppObject>() { new AppObject() {Value=2}});     
    collection.Sum(l => l.Value.Sum(v => v.Value)); // this line of code should do the job.
```